# Embedding Apache fop 2.1 in java servlet

Tags: java, servlets, fonts, apache-fop

I have an application that uses Apache FOP to generate PDF files. Everything works great, except Cyrillic letters in the generated PDF. As far as I understand, I am supposed to bundle font that has Cyrillic letters with the application.

So, I set the application as follows: 
I have config file in ../src/main/resources/conf/fop.xml (pretty much default one for PDF renderer) and initialise FOP like this:

```
FopFactoryBuilder fopBuilder =
  new FopFactoryBuilder(fileLoader.getFile("conf/fop.xml").toURI(),
    new ClasspathResolverURIAdapter());
fopFactory = fopBuilder.build();
```

fileLoader is my own utility for reading files, XSLT is loaded by it and everything works great. I tried another ways to do so, with no luck. Fop itself works great, except for the fonts.

In config I have:

```
<renderers>
    <renderer mime="application/pdf">
      <filterList>
        <value>flate</value>
      </filterList>
      <fonts>
        <directory recursive="true">./</directory>
        <auto-detect/>
      </fonts>
    </renderer>
  </renderers>
```

Fonts are in subdirectory under conf/.

My XSLT references the fonts and via command-line everything works fine, I get the result I want, so I guess, that XSLT is correct.

I see two problems:

- I do not see any reaction from fop runtime, when I change the config, even if I make it broken.
- Fonts, of course, are not loaded.

Probably I am missing something very obvious here and hope that someone could guide me.

Comment: Usually non-latin / nonstandard fonts need be EMEBEDDED in PDF documents. Details depends on technology, I dont know FOP, but many tools have similar behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you are ***not*** using your configuration file, so the fonts are not configured and they are not embedded in the PDF output.

The `URI` parameter in the `FopFactoryBuilder` constructor is used to **resolve relative URIs**, not to load the configuration file.

As per [embedding instructions](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.2/embedding.html#config-external), your code should have something similar to this:

```
import org.apache.avalon.framework.configuration.Configuration;
import org.apache.avalon.framework.configuration.DefaultConfigurationBuilder;

...

DefaultConfigurationBuilder cfgBuilder = new DefaultConfigurationBuilder();
Configuration cfg = cfgBuilder.buildFromFile(new File("conf/conf.xml"));
FopFactoryBuilder fopFactoryBuilder = new FopFactoryBuilder(new File(".").toURI()).setConfiguration(cfg);
FopFactory fopFactory = fopFactoryBuilder.build();
```

Comment: That is _very_ obvious thing to miss. Thanks.